# Firebase Auth: with Sign in existing user

Tags: java, android, firebase-authentication

when a sign in existing user with same email address and password, response always be "Can not sign in, Please check your email and password and try again"

```
private void loginUser(String email, String password) {

    mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

            if (!task.isSuccessful()){ 

               mLoginProgress.dismiss();  

                Intent mainIntent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(mainIntent);
                finish();
            }
            else {
                mLoginProgress.hide();

                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,
                        "Cannot sign in. Please check your email and password and try again.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when response is a success , you are turning it into failure by using `!` where it mean

```
(!task.isSuccessful()) => (!true)
=> (false)
```

so remove negation operator (`!`)

```
if (task.isSuccessful())
```

Code

```
mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

            if (task.isSuccessful()){ // success
                //..code
            }
            else {  // failure
                //..code
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you ! @Pavneet_Singh :)

Comment: @GayaniMadahapola i am glad that i could help, happy coding :)

Answer (score 2):

This is because you have used '!' NOT opertor with success, i.e if the login is not successful then it will enter if clause, remove the ! and it will work properly.

Comment: kindly award the right answer to @pavneet as he was first. Thanks